# Why is my global variable shadowed before the local declaration?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

```
x = 1; 
alert(x); 
var y = function() { 
    alert(x); 
    var x = 2; 
    alert(x); 
} 
y();
```

The result of the 3 alerts is: `1`, `undefined`, `2` (Chrome 25)

My question is: why the second alert is undefined? Why not 1? Isn't there a global variable x?

Comment: Because you shadow `x` in your function. So there is a function-scoped variable `x`, that hasn't been assigned a value yet so you get undefined. This is why it is always recommended to declare your variables at the start of the function, because it will get done for you anyway. Try not to confuse yourself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Due to [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), this is what gets executed:

```
x = 1; 
alert(x); 
var y = function() { 
    var x; // <-- this gets hoisted up from where it was.

    alert(x); 
    x = 2; 
    alert(x); 
} 
y();
```

At the start of function `y()`, the local variable `x` is declared but not initialized.

Comment: but if the "x" is "hoisting" , isn't there a conflict? because there is already a "x=1"? Which declaration is the first? the "hoisting x" or the "x=1"?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have "conflicts" it "shadows". The local variable "shadows" any variables with the same name is a higher scope. So later when you use `x` it is using the local-most scope. The global one is defined first, but in the scope of `y` the local one is used.

Comment: The way scoping works is that javascript first looks in the local scope for the variable x. If it finds it, it stops looking, so we never get to the global x. If it doesn't find it, it moves up a level to whatever the scope was when the function was declared, and searches there with the same pattern. (In this case, it finds the declaration then, since it's reached the global scope). So, basically, it works like an onion, inside out.

Answer (score 2):

The variable declaration in the function is hoisted to the top. So it technically looks like this:

```
var y = function() {
    var x;

    alert(x);

    x = 2;
};
```

The local variable overshadows the global one. That is why the alert returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Since scope in JavaScript is a function object. When you execute some code in a function(your code sample), "alert(x)" will find if there's any definition of "x" in the function. So, there's a "var x = 2" in this function. But the JavaScript runtime will explain your code like this:

```
x = 1; 
alert(x); 
var y = function() { 
  var x;
  alert(x); 
  x = 2; 
  alert(x); 
} 
y();
```

So, the x in the second alert is "undefined" not "1". So when you declare some variable in a function, I recommend you to declare the variables in the top of your function.